# How can I change the local port kubectl uses to establish a connection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I want kubectl to use a different local port- not 22. Is this configurable? Is this something I have to configure in ssh?

I want to create an ssh tunnel with IAP first and have kubeclt use that to connect to a private cluster.

```
I create the tunnel like this:

gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel --project "myproject" \
    "nodex-default-pool-abc123-1xc8" 22 --local-host-port=localhost:2200
```

Now I'd like kubectl to use it to connect via local port `2200`

I want to avoid having a bastion vm and just leverage IAP.

I tried to set the HTTPS_PROXY but does not appear to work:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:2200 kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: malformed HTTP response "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5"
```

EDIT: I also tried to open a tunnel to the control plane but it looks like GKE doesn't support IAP for authentication?

```
PROJECT_ID=myproject
ZONE=us-central1-b
REGION=us-central1
NETWORK=mynetwork

MASTER_IP=$(gcloud container clusters describe mycluster --zone $ZONE --project $PROJECT_ID --format=json | jq .endpoint -r)

gcloud alpha compute start-iap-tunnel $MASTER_IP 443 --project $PROJECT_ID --network=$NETWORK --region=$REGION \
         --local-host-port=localhost:4444

Testing if tunnel connection works.
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.start-iap-tunnel) While checking if a connection can be made: Error while connecting [4033: 'not authorized'].
```

Perhaps IAP requires a DNS name to initiate google auth or something? I also tried just connecting to the cluster name itself, but that returned a connection error.

Comment: You're trying to point `kubectl` -- a tool which speaks HTTP -- to an `ssh` port. That's not going to work.

Comment: Updated with attempt to connect to control plane with IAP

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-gke-private-clusters-through-iap-14fedad694f8) related to your concern about connecting to your private cluster using IAP. In which, they explained there are possible ways to proceed. In the article attached, some pre-requisites were met before providing a command on the client machine.

Comment: I want to know if I can _avoid_ a jump box which is the approach this article describes.

Comment: I checked other articles and it seems that its not possible avoiding a jump box